# ActiveMQ multiple MessageListener for queue doesn't seem working properly

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

The scenario is, i've setup two DefaultMessageListenerContainer, like this:

```
DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = createListenerContainer(queueName, groupName, listener);
container.setDestination(getDestination(queueName, prefetchSize));
container.setConcurrentConsumers(consumers);
container.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(consumers);
container.setCacheLevel(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.CACHE_CONNECTION);
container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
container.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
container.setMessageListener(listener);
container.setMessageSelector(selector);
container.initialize();
container.start();
```

While selector is different, one is "groupName <> 'A'" with 15 consumers, and the other is "groupName = 'A'" with 2 consumers.

In my case, each message would take about 6 mins or longer to be completely consumed.

I used to setup only one MessageListener without selector before, it works properly.

But now i can observe blocking everywhere, messages with groupName <> 'A' won't be consumed occasionally even there is a lot of messages in queue.

I can see that these MessageListenerContainers are using different connection, so i am confused why they affect each other.